# Optimizing dbt Pipeline Performance for Time Series Data Imputation

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I'm building a dbt pipeline with PostgreSQL. One of my initial tables contains time series data with columns 'group_id', 'timestamp', and various numeric columns.

I'd like to create a downstream model that fills missing numeric values in the time series data with the previous (by 'group_id') row's value or, if that doesn't exist, with the average value across the whole table. I need to perform this sort of cleanup for six columns.

I've written some code that does this correctly, but my initial table has about 1.2 million records, and running `dbt run -s "my-model"` takes *forever*. I killed it after an hour last time.

The code is below. Can you think of a more performant way to fill in these missing values? I tried to think of ways to help with an intermediate dbt model but have come up empty so far.

```
with avg_stats as (select avg(stat_1) as avg_stat_1,
                          avg(stat_2) as avg_stat_2,
                          ...
                    from my_db.my_table),

select stats.group_id,
       stats.timestamp,
       coalesce(
               stats.stat_1,
               coalesce(
                       (select previous.stat_1
                                from my_db.my_table previous
                                where
                                    previous.group_id = stats.group_id and
                                    previous.stat_1 is not null and
                                    previous.timestamp < stats.timestamp
                                order by previous.timestamp desc
                                limit 1),
                       avg_stat_1)
       ) as stat_1,
       coalesce(
               stats.stat_2,
               coalesce(
                       (select previous.stat_2
                                from my_db.my_table previous
                                where
                                    previous.group_id = stats.group_id and
                                    previous.stat_2 is not null and
                                    previous.timestamp < stats.timestamp
                                order by previous.timestamp desc
                                limit 1),
                       avg_stat_2)
       ) as stat_2,
       ...
from my_db.my_table stats;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a method that works quite nicely.

```
with avg_stats as (select avg(stat_1) as avg_stat_1,
                          avg(stat_2) as avg_stat_2,
                          ...
                    from my_db.my_table),

     partitioned as (select group_id,
                            timestamp,
                            stat_1,
                            sum(case when stat_1 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                            over (order by group_id, timestamp) as stat_1_partition_id,
                            stat_2,
                            sum(case when stat_2 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                            over (order by group_id, timestamp) as stat_2_partition_id,
                    from my_db.my_table)

select group_id,
       timestamp,
       coalesce(
               first_value(stat_1)
               over (partition by stat_1_partition_id order by group_id),
               avg_stat_1
       ) as stat_1,
       coalesce(
               first_value(stat_2)
               over (partition by stat_2_partition_id order by group_id),
               avg_stat_2
       ) as stat_2,
       ...
from partitioned;
```

When using this type of query as part of my dbt model with 1.2 million records and table materialization, `dbt run -s my_model` completed in 2.5 minutes. Good enough for me.